# Editing stylehseet url in head section of WordPress

Tags: php, css, html

In our website, in the `<head>` section there is a call to a stylesheet and the URL is unsecured (HTTP). I would like to edit this to be `https`, but I'm not sure what file to edit to achieve this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide us with more info?  What theme or plugin is this in relation to, what files can you edit, etc.  There's a bunch of different ways this could potentially be solved but no one can tell you what the right one is without knowing what you're working with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We are using Ciya shop woocommerce/wordpress theme. I checked the header.php file and it doesn't list the stylesheet calls in there. it only shows <?php wp_head(); ?>